# Can interval notation be used to describe a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

If $x$ is an element of the set of integers between 4 and 14 inclusive, some might say

$ x \in Z \hspace{1mm} , \hspace{1mm} 4\le x\le14 $

or

$ x \in $ { $4,5,...,14$}

I wonder whether this notation seen in an old textbook is considered valid

$ x \in Z [4,14] $

It seems to have disappeared from modern literature.

Comment: I confess that this notation is new for me. I would write $x\in\mathbb{Z}\cap[4,14]$.

Comment: In old math writings, $AB$ was written for intersection and $A+B$ for union.  So maybe this is really the same as $\mathbb Z \cap [4,14]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the use of
$$\; x \in \mathbb{Z} [4,14]\;\text{ to denote the set of integers:}\;\{4, 5, 6, ..., 14\}$$
has "gone by the wayside" (disappeared) in modern literature for a very good reason, as it is rather ambiguous, and (e.g.) looks far too similar to $\mathbb{Z}[p]$, which has an entirely different meaning than what you intend it to denote. (Also, as Sigur comments below, $\mathbb{Z}[a, b]$ can be used to denote the polynomial ring on variables $a, b$.)

The other notations you mention are much less ambiguous, as is $x\in \mathbb{Z} \cap [4, 14]$

Comment: Why do you say it is ambiguous? To what unintended values may this notation map x?

Comment: I just think, as it is rather uncommon, that it leaves reader having to "guess" the intended meaning, which they may guess correctly, but "guessing" leaves open the door for mis-guessing.

Comment: Also, $\mathbb{Z}[a,b]$ could be used to denote the polynomial ring on variables $a,b$ over the integers.

Comment: i didn't see such that notation, Z[a,b]!!

Answer (score 1):

Given a [partial ordered set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) (or [poset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set)) $(P,\leq)$ and $x,y\in P$, the interval $[x,y\textbf{]}$ is defined as $(\mathord{\uparrow}x)\cap(\mathord{\downarrow} y)$, where $\mathord{\uparrow} x=\{p\in P:x\leq p\}$ and $\mathord{\downarrow}y=\{p\in P: p\leq y\}$. Note that $P$ doesn't even need to be totally ordered for intervals to exist.

Specifically about your question, if you make it clear that you're working on the poset $(\mathbb{Z},\leq)$, there shouldn't be any problem with that notation.

Comment: But specifying that s/he is working with the poset $(\mathbb{Z}, \leq)$ adds more baggage than the alternative notations! $[4, 14]\subseteq (\mathbb{Z}, \leq)$...

Comment: @amWhy I'm not saying I disagree, but it probably depends on how often you're going to use that notation. Also if you're in the context of discrete mathematics, it might come in handy.