# Does $x \in [0, 1]$ mean $x = 0 \lor x = 1$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the following notation:

$x  \in [0, 1]$

Does this mean that $x$ can be *any* rational number between 0 and 1 inclusive, or does it mean that either $x = 0$ or $x = 1$?

Comment: Neither - it means that $x$ can be any real number such that $0 \le x \le 1$.

Comment: See [the definiton of interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics))

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296638/can-interval-notation-be-used-to-describe-a-set).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $[0,1]$ is the set of real numbers $\{x\in \mathbb R \colon 0\le x \le 1\}$.